# Is there a strategy for the predator and prey which is strictly dominant?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

> Let us consider a prey and a predator. The predator wants to hunt a prey, and it has two choices: either stay Active (search for prey) or Passive (wait for the prey). Similarly, the prey wants to avoid the predator and has same choices as the predator: Active (build a safe zone) or Passive (do nothing for safety). 
>   $$\begin{array}{c|cc}
> & A & P\\ \hline
> A & 3,-0.8 & 4, -1\\
> P & 2,-0.1 & 0,0\end{array}$$
>   Row is predator, Column is prey.

Are there strictly dominant strategies for the predator or the prey? If yes, what are they (active/passive)? If no, why not?

Comment: Please do not change the edits, which are improve your question.

Comment: @jacmeird Edits can be rolled back depending on the context, in this instance however, I agree with you.

Comment: @Bacon Yeah, sorry. I didn't want to be impolite!

Comment: The matrix was displayed in a single line so I had to roll it back.

Comment: Currently there is a $2 \times 5$ matrix. Please clarify what the payoff matrix is.

Comment: It's 2x2 the 1,2 in first column is to denote the row number.

Comment: Idk why it isn't displayed as row1 and row2

Comment: Can you write the payoff matrix in a more common fashion? Typically, an entry of a payoff matrix is A,B where A is the payoff to row player and B is the payoff to column player. As it is written write now I have no idea what are the payoffs.

Comment: Row 1 3,-0.8         4,-1

Comment: Row 2   2,-0.1         0,0

Comment: It's predator/prey

Answer (score 1):

The strategy $A$ is strictly dominant for the Row player. By playing $A$ versus $B$ he gets $3 > 2$ when Column plays $A$ and $4 > 0$ when Column plays $B$.

Column has no dominant strategies. However, the game is dominance solvable. Once Column knows that $B$ is dominated for Row, Column knows that Row will play $A$ and hence best replies to $A$ by choosing $A$ because $-0.8>-1$. So the unique strategy profile that survives iterated deletion of strictly dominated strategies is $(A,A)$.